# jquery traversing box disappearing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am traversing using a prev and next button. Seems like it is breaking if I keep clicking. I simply want if i click the back or next button for it to not break.

```js
var $currDiv = $("#start");
$("div").hide();
$currDiv.css("background", "red");
$("#1").click(function() {
    $currDiv = $currDiv.next();
    $("div").hide();
    $currDiv.show();
});

var $currDiv2 = $("#startPrev");
$("div").hide();
$currDiv2.css("background", "red");
$("#2").click(function() {
    $currDiv2 = $currDiv2.prev();
    $("div").hide();
    $currDiv2.show();
});
```

```css
 div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px black solid;
    padding: 3px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button id ="1">Next</button></p>  <p><button id="2">Back</button></p> 
<div id="start">div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<div>div3</div>
<div>div4</div>
<div>div5</div>
<div id="startPrev">div6</div>
```

Comment: What is breaking exactly? What causes an unintended result, what *is* that unintended result, and what would you like to happen instead?

Comment: Notice if you keep clicking the back or next button, everything dissapears. How do I keep it on div1 - div6 only?

Comment: Okay. Rather than storing the current div itself in a variable, you might store the index number of that variable in a variable, then access it via `$("#someParent:nth-child("+currentDivIndex+")")`

Comment: I do not understand that. Can you simplify

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a bad explanation. I have now written an answer with a fully functioning demo of code like I described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I perhaps went a little overboard here. Instead of keeping the current div in a variable, I keep the *index* of the current element in a variable, which is a bit easier to work with. I put all the divs inside a parent element (#parent) so that we can easily select only the divs we care about with the selector "#parent>div".

```js
var currIndex = 0; // start at the first element
showCurrentDiv();

// hide all divs, then show only the current one
function showCurrentDiv() {
    // hide all divs inside #parent
    $("#parent>div").hide();
    // of all divs inside #parent, show the nth div, where n=currIndex
    $("#parent>div:eq("+currIndex+")").show(); 
}

$("#1").click(function() {
    // if current div is not the very last div...
    if (currIndex < $("#parent>div").length - 1) {
        currIndex++; // ...then traverse to the next div
    }
    showCurrentDiv(); // update which divs are shown/hidden
});

$("#2").click(function() {
    // if current div is not the very first div...
    if (currIndex > 0) {
        currIndex--; // ...then traverse to the previous div
    }
    showCurrentDiv(); // update which divs are shown/hidden
});
```

```css
 #parent>div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px black solid;
    padding: 3px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button id ="1">Next</button></p>  <p><button id="2">Back</button></p> 
<div id="parent">
    <div>div1</div>
    <div>div2</div>
    <div>div3</div>
    <div>div4</div>
    <div>div5</div>
    <div>div6</div>
</div>
```

Normally answers aren't supposed to just rewrite code, but I hope I have at least thoroughly explained everything I did. I used the :eq() selector to specify which div I want to show, which is documented [here](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/); basically it selects the nth element that matches the selector.

Comment: The first iteration of this answer didn't work, but I have now edited it and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it for you:

```
var $currDiv = $("#start");
$("div").hide();
$currDiv.css("background", "red");
$("#1").click(function() {
    $currDiv = $currDiv.next();
    if ($currDiv.length) {
        $("div").hide();
        $currDiv.show();
    }
    else
    {
        currDiv = $("#startPrev");
    }

});



var $currDiv2 = $("#startPrev");
$("div").hide();
$currDiv2.css("background", "red");
$("#2").click(function() {
    $currDiv2 = $currDiv2.prev();
    if ($currDiv2.length) {
        $("div").hide();
        $currDiv2.show();
    }
    else
    {
        $currDiv2 = $("#start");
    }

});
```

Comment: still breaks. I have to restart to get back to div1